# How to create a binary image from array with opencv?

Tags: opencv

I am new to opencv and I have a data array for a binary image, like [1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1...]. My goal is to read it in opencv and manipulate it with opencv functions, so how to create a binary image from raw data array with opencv?

Comment: This could help you..[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599395/opencv-create-mat-from-byte-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599395/opencv-create-mat-from-byte-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can easily create a Mat from that data :

```
unsigned char bits[] = {1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1};
Mat m( 3,3, CV_8UC1, bits );
```

if your bits were an int[]  you'd have to use  CV_32SC1.